# How to create a translatable successful notice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I am trying to create a translatable successful notice. This notice would be called by a successful call of the create and update actions.

This is what I have so far:

```
#config/locales/en.yml
activerecord:
  models:
    place: "Place"
  successful:
    messages:
      created: "%{model} was successfully created."
      updated: "%{model} was successfully updated."

#app/controllers/places_controller.rb
def create
  ...
  format.html { redirect_to(@place, :notice => "#{t 'activerecord.successful.messages.created'}") }
```

The problem is that this shows the message: "%{model} was successfully created.". How do I get it to say: "Place was successfully created."?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use i18n's interpolation functions (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation) do do something like

```
t('activerecord.successful.messages.created', :model => @my_newly_saved_object.class.model_name.human)
```

where `model_name` returns the name of the class of the created object (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html). calling `human` on this object returns the i18n translation of the model name (from the scope activerecord.models.{model_name})

Comment: This approach imho is excessively wordy, you don't need all that, you'll be calling the `t` helper in the controller (the `places_controller` in your case), in where you already know which model you are saving just write `model: :place` and get the same result, way easier to read

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
format.html do
  redirect_to(
    @place, 
    notice: t('activerecord.successful.messages.created', model: :place
  )
end
```

(Note that you are writing this in the `places_controller.rb` file, so you know it will be a `place` being saved, no need for `@place.class.model_name.human` wordy stuff.)

This will tell the i18n the translation of which `model` to use, now you just need to localize the model names, which is very simple and done by adding the `model` section within the `activerecord` one, so your locale yaml files will look like:

```
activerecord:
    successful:
      messages:
        created: 
          enqueued: "La creazione del %{model} è stata messa in coda con successo"
    error_header_message: 
      one: Un errore ha proibito il salvataggio di questo %{model}
      other: "%{count} errori hanno proibito il salvataggio di questo %{model}"
    models: 
      article: articolo
    attributes:
      article: 
        user_id: Autore
        title: Titolo
        published: Pubblicato
        text: Testo
```

Similarly, as you can see in the example,  you can specify also attribute names which is going to be useful in forms, error validations and other places.